# Code Coverage Comparison algorithm for python

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverage.py, python-unittest

Which tools are readily available or that I can develop upon for Python, that will tell me what percentage of code is actually covered by unit tests?

Previously I've developed a code coverage tool called Haystack. Haystack works by running the test when it last passed.
After that, it runs the test when it required investigation. Compares the results.
It runs the tests with code coverage, which determines the lines of code the test executed.

I have used coverage.py but it only gives a report based on code in repository vs. code that can actually run, and not what percentage is covered by my unit tests. Anyone can suggest a library or tool? I am using Python on Ubuntu with PyCharm (community).

Comment: Oh yes, Haystack was in C# and I have now moved to a job where we dev in Python (I used OpenCover, for comparison algorithm before), which is not available for non .Net platforms.

Comment: _I have used coverage.py but it only gives a report based on code in repository vs. code that can actually run_ can you clarify? How do you run `coverage` tool? Usually you do something like `coverage run run_all_of_my_unittests.py` and `coverage html` to retrieve results.

Comment: I'm interested to hear more about how coverage.py isn't doing what you need.  It's used by most Python programmers to do exactly what you want: tell them what percentage of code is covered by their unit tests.